# How to run Android arm64 or armeabi-v7a emulator on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, ubuntu-18.04

I'm trying to set up an Android emulator on Ubuntu 18.04. I've managed to get Android Studio running. However, it can only run emulators that support ABI/CPU x86. If I try running emulators with Virtual Devices for arm64 or armeabi-v7a, the emulator simply freezes. These are the logs:

```
12:54 PM Emulator: statvfs('/home/pc/.android/avd/Pixel_2_API_25_32b.avd/snapshots/default_boot/ram.img') failed: No such file or directory

12:54 PM Emulator: Warning: QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR points to non-existing path '/run/user/1000/snap.android-studio', please create it with 0700 permissions. ((null):0, (null))

12:54 PM Emulator: Warning: QXcbIntegration: Cannot create platform OpenGL context, neither GLX nor EGL are enabled ((null):0, (null))

12:54 PM Emulator: ERROR: Unable to access '/home/pc/.emulator_console_auth_token': emulator console will not work

12:54 PM Emulator: Warning: restoring GLES1 context from snapshot. App may need reloading.

12:54 PM Emulator: emulator: WARNING: IniFile.cpp:235: Failed to open .ini file /home/pc/.android/emu-update-last-check.ini for writing.
```

I need those configurations because the APK I want to work with does not support x86 architectures.

Does anyone maybe know how to make Virtual Devices with these specs work on Android Studio for Ubuntu 18, or is there maybe another way to run an APK which is not x86 compatible?

To give you a full picture, I want to automate testing with Appium (or other similar software). So, if there is another reliable way, other than Android Studio, to run arm64 or armeabi-v7a emulators which can then be accessed by Appium (or other automation software), that would also be great. I tried Anbox, but it lags all the time.

Many thanks!

Comment: This question deals with the same issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70251107/which-android-virtual-device-should-be-used-to-launch-arm64-v8a-apk-on-windows

Answer (score 1):

Used docker for running emulator on arm64 on ubuntu 21.04.
There are few ready built docker images available like [redroid](https://hub.docker.com/r/redroid/redroid)