# Cannot start up ARM64-v8a based emulator in Android Studio Chipmunk

Tags: android, emulation

I am unable to start up an ARM-based emulator in Android Studio Chipmunk.  Getting the error:

```
 PANIC: Avd's CPU Architecture 'arm64' is not supported by the QEMU2 emulator on x86_64 host.
```

I am running Android Studio an a MacBook with Intel core i7 chipset.  The x86_64-based emulators come up fine.  Is it not possible to run an ARM-based emulator with the Intel core i7 chipset?  The reason I wanted to use an ARM-based emulator is because I have an executable with these properties:

```
 ELF executable, 64-bit LSB arm64, static, not stripped
```

so I thought I have to use an ARM-based emulator to run this executable.  Is this not right, i.e., would it be possible to run this arm64 executable in an x86_64 based emulator?  TIA for any info.

Comment: See: https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2020/03/run-arm-apps-on-android-emulator.html and [Which Android Virtual Device should be used to launch arm64-v8a APK on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71216466/295004)

Comment: Thanks Morrison.  As one of the posts mentions, I could try dropping back to the Nougat version for arm64 so I'll see if that works...

Comment: do not use ARM system image for Android 
28 and above, FYI:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74760054/panic-avds-cpu-architecture-arm64-is-not-supported-by-the-qemu2-emulator-on