# PANIC: Avd's CPU Architecture 'arm64' is not supported by the QEMU2 emulator on x86_64 host

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-virtual-device, avd-manager

When I try to run on windows this command :

> emulator.exe -avd android13

Where android13 is an arm64 avd I receive the error :

```
INFO    | Android emulator version 31.3.13.0 (build_id 9189900) (CL:N/A)
emulator: INFO: Found systemPath c:\Users\zeus\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\system-images\android-33\google_apis\arm64-v8a\
PANIC: Avd's CPU Architecture 'arm64' is not supported by the QEMU2 emulator on x86_64 host.
```

I'm on windows 10. How can I run an AVD with arm64 cpu architecture?

Comment: Possibly duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/a/71216466/6576302

Answer (score 48, accepted):

ARM64 emulation on a `x86_64` host currently is only possible up to API level 27 Oreo:

```
#ifdef __x86_64__
  if (sarch == "arm64" && apiLevel >=28) {
      APANIC("Avd's CPU Architecture '%s' is not supported by the QEMU2 emulator on x86_64 host.\n", avdarch);
  }
#endif
```

You'd need an ARM64 CPU to run `android-33`:

```
#if defined(__aarch64__)
  if (sarch != "arm64") {
      APANIC("Avd's CPU Architecture '%s' is not supported by the QEMU2 emulator on aarch64 host.\n", avdarch);
  }
#endif
```

Comment: thanks martin, but I build my app with Delphi that produce native assembly :(

Comment: Using a hardware device might be the most reliable option for latest API on ARM64. MacBook M1 might eventually also be able to run the emulator; that's at least what the source code says.

Comment: thanks martin but do you know with hardware device I can found (except the macbook that is very expensive) to launch the emulator on arm ?

Comment: You're not launching anything on ARM, this is x86_64. Consumer grade hardware devices are much cheaper than a MacBook M1/M2; you'll have to invest about 200-300 EUR for that. I don't know why it's disabled for x86_64, but likely there is a god reason for it, which means a custom emulator won't help.

Comment: I have a pretty interesting behaviour. `uname -p` returning `arm` but when I trying to start emu with avd
```
INFO    | Android emulator version 31.3.14.0 (build_id 9322596) (CL:N/A)
emulator: INFO: Found systemPath /Users/tcagent/Library/Android/sdk/system-images/android-31/google_apis/arm64-v8a/
PANIC: Avd's CPU Architecture 'arm64' is not supported by the QEMU2 emulator on x86_64 host.
```

Comment: Incredible that Android Studio does not warn you before hand or come with any understandable error when trying to launch Android 33 image! We have to open idea.log to find out AFTER installing an image that doesn't run.