# Android Emulator ARM64 won't start "The emulator process for AVD Pixel_6_Pro_API_33_ARM64 has terminated." But x86_64 works fine

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-virtual-device, avd-manager

I am unable to start ARM64 emulator on my Windows 10 system but x86_64 works fine. Intel HAXM installed successfully, so of course virtualization is enabled

[image]

What can be the reason?

DualCore Intel Core i5-7300U

**Update**

Running an emulator from the console it prints the next error:

`PANIC: Avd's CPU Architecture 'arm64' is not supported by the QEMU2 emulator on x86_64 host`

**Update 2**

It seems we can not use newer Android API for ARM64 emulator on x86_64 systems - https://stackoverflow.com/a/74819011/7767664